# gazebo is running but black screen is coming.how can i solve this problem. i m using ubuntu 16.04 ros kinetic gazebo 7.0

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/21960/gazebo-is-running-but-black-screen-is-coming.how-can-i-solve-this-problem.-i-m-using-ubuntu-16.04-ros-kinetic-gazebo-7.0/) by [emre](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/8379/emre/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-02-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Take a look at the error messages:

`terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::filesystem:filesystem_error' ... Permission denied...`

Make sure that Gazebo has permissions to write to `~/.gazebo`

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2019-02-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [emre](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/8379/emre/) on 2019-02-20**:
How can i fix it

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2019-02-20**:
You can try deleting the `~/.gazebo` directory and let Gazebo recreate it the next time it runs, this may fix the problem. If it doesn't, you'll need to investigate the directory's permissions and the permissions when running Gazebo.

**Comment by [emre](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/8379/emre/) on 2019-02-21**:
Thank you so much it worked. Take care of yourself! thanks again